# How do I get the effect below using js jquery or any other plugin?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, uislider

[image: On the desktop]

[image: On the mobile view]

Note:See images

What I want is that on normal desktop view the divs, (containing the image and paragraph) all of them should be displayed but in the mobile site I want a horizontal slider with swipe and only one div to be displayed at a time and slidable.

I am using bootstrap jquery and ready to use any other plugin reqd.

How do I achieve this effect

Comment: This should be possible with Bootstrap itself. Check this [website](http://www.indisparks.com) and confirm if this is the element-wise effect that you want

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar. On the mobile site you set all of them except for the one you want to show on page load to

```
display:none;
```

Then in Jquery/JS you basically have to toggle the other divs. So when your button is clicked, the Jquery hides all the other divs if they are already visible and then "toggles" (makes visible) the one they clicked on.

You can use this snippet for each step/button to be clicked:

The way it works is, if you click the button for Div2, it hides div1 or div3 if they are visible. Then it unhides Div2.

```
  $('#Button_Div2').click(function(){
  $('.Div1:visible').toggle("slide");
  $('.Div3:visible').toggle("slide");

  $('.Div2:hidden').toggle("slide");
  });
```